# Block diagram reduction to get characteristic equation

Tags: control-theory

[image]

Given the control system above I need to show that the characteristic equation is: $$5s^3+(25+K+5p)s^2+(25p+Kp+K)s+5K=0$$

I have used the block diagram reduction rules but I end up with an equation that looks like this:
$$\frac{K}{(s+p)(k+5s+25)+K}$$

How would be the correct block diagram reduction process?

Comment: Just replace every feedback loop by one equivalent block, starting with the inner most one and using that find the next one, ect.

Comment: Start from K and 1/(s+5). After that, you will see it flows quickly